# Omit subfolders when exporting CloudWatch to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have a lambda function to export CloudWatch logs to an S3 bucket:

```
import { Handler, SQSEvent } from 'aws-lambda'
import {
  CloudWatchLogsClient,
  CreateExportTaskCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-cloudwatch-logs'

const cloudWatchLogsClient = new CloudWatchLogsClient({
  region: '*****',
})

export const handler: Handler<SQSEvent, string> = async (_, context) => {
  const thirtyMinutesAgo = new Date(
    new Date().getTime() - 30 * 60 * 1000,
  ).getTime()

  await cloudWatchLogsClient.send(
    new CreateExportTaskCommand({
      destination: '*****',
      from: thirtyMinutesAgo,
      to: new Date().getTime(),
      logGroupName: '*****',
    }),
  )

  return Promise.resolve(context.logStreamName)
}
```

It works, but exports to a new folder with another folder containing a single file every time:

```
exportedlogs/
0484a866-210f-43a3-ad09-62b21e19ebc7/
event/000000.gz
```

I want to set up AWS Glue + AWS Athena to go through these logs but I got stuck with reading through these folders.

1. Is there a way to configure the export task and write it into `exportedlogs/{number}.gz`?
2. If not, is using CloudWatch SDK + S3 SDK to do manual exports a good approach?
3. Is it better to configure AWS Glue to somehow *flatten* the structure?